# Is it Facebook User ID have longer version?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We know every Facebook account has a User ID, for example Mark Zuckerberg's Facebook User ID is **4**, and my Facebook User ID is **100001587846535**. And we know we can get Facebook User ID by using tool such as findmyfbid.com or by using Facebook Graph API. And we can also go to our Facebook profile by using this link https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=[YourFbUserID] alternatively.

Anyway, when I playing an Android game that using Facebook login for sign in authentication, I sniff the network that Android game using a longer version of my Facebook User ID that value is **1598720750190838** instead of my real Facebook User ID which is **100001587846535**. Yes I believe this is a longer version of my User ID, because when I type https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=[MyLongerFbUserID] it will also redirect to my Facebook profile.

So what did you call of this longer version of Facebook User ID?
How do I can get a longer version of Facebook User ID of other Facebook profile account?

I tried to looking for in Facebook Developer Graph documentation, I found third_party_id but I don't think what I mean about.

Comment: Since API v2.0 user ids are app-scoped, to better protect user’s privacy - every 3rd-party app that the user logs into gets to see a _different_ id.

Comment: @CBroe then how to get other person's app-scoped user ids?

Comment: You get the app-scoped user id, when the user logs into your app.